Which dinosaur laid the eggs that Dr Grant found?
In Jurassic Park, after escaping the T-Rex and sleeping the night in the tree. Dr Grant, Lex and Tim find eggs in the roots of a tree, and Dr Grant exclaims that 'life did find a way'.
Which dinosaur laid those eggs?


Nothing useful in the Koepp script; "They stare in amazement - - - - at a whole clutch of dinosaur eggs!  All hatched, now empty. Grant picks up one of the fragments, a large one - nearly half an egg."

Nothing useful in the graphic novel; https://i.sstatic.net/nrLXc.jpg

Nothing useful in the junior novelisation; “What is it?” asked Tim. Alan was holding a thin piece of white shell. “It’s a dinosaur egg,” Alan said. Part of him couldn’t believe it. But another part wasn’t surprised at all. “The dinosaurs are breeding.” Right in front of him was a whole group of eggs that were already hatched.

https://www.thefossilforum.com/topic/92371-advanced-dinosaur-egg-guide/ there's a nice picture from Royal Tyrrell museum comparing shapes.  A velociraptor egg is the most "egg" shaped as opposed to spherical or extreme oval like other residents of jurassic park.

In Jurassic Park 3, we see the same kind of eggs again, and this time they are clearly explained as Velociraptor eggs

In the original novel Grant finds a velociraptor eggshell.

Grant shook his head. “Look at the curvature. The shell is almost flat. That's from a very big egg. And notice the thickness of the shell. Unless you have ostriches on this island, it's a dinosaur egg.”
“But they can't possibly breed,” Harding insisted. “All the animals are female.”
“All I know,” Grant said, “is that this is a dinosaur egg.”
Malcolm said, “Can you tell the species?”
“Yes,” Grant said. “It's a velociraptor egg.”

Note that this scene (in the book) happens rather earlier than the film, when Grant and Ellie are investigating the sickly triceratops.
